# JQuery get all the tr in a table that is after a tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've few tables like this in the same page:

```
<table>
<tr class="head">
    <th>
        Brand
    </th>
</tr>
<tr class="attributeVal">
    <td>
        text
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="attributeVal">
    <td>
        text
    </td>
</tr>
....
</table>
```

And there is in page load

```
$('.attributeVal').hide();
```

The idea is when 'head' gets mouseover to show all the 'attributeVal' classes that is in the same table. I cat do $('.attributeVal') because it effect all the 'attributeVal' that is on the page.

Also,  Once I leave that table all the 'attributeVal' in the current table will hide().

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method shows the rows on mouseover, and hides them when hovering away. Replace `.toggle()` with `.show()` if you want to keep the rows visible.

```
$('table').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.attributeVal').hide();
});
$('.head').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.attributeVal').show();
});
```

Using [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t7CWp/ (also works with jQuery 1.5.1).

Comment: There is one problem with your answers (all of you). The problem is that I need 'attributeVal' in the current table will hide() once the mouse leaves the table(and not only 'head').

Comment: @nir We are not mind readers. Can you update the question with the exact requirements?

Comment: @nir I updated my answer, so it does exactly what you want (see jsfiddle)

Comment: @nir Updated answer. I use a method which is compatible with jQuery 1.5.1, since you mentioned that you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the containing table to the `.attributeVal` selector as a context, so that you only select matching elements from within the current table:

```
$(".head").mouseover(function() {
    $(".attributeVal", $(this).closest("table")).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the .siblings() method. It selects all siblings (matching the optional selector).

To hide the elements only when leaving the table, use the `mouseleave` event on the table:

```
$('.head').on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).siblings('.attributeVal').show();
})
$('table').on('mouseleave',function() {
    $(this).find('.attributeVal').hide();
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATWFH/

Also instead of hiding the `.attributeVal` on page load with javascript, you could just give them a style, so they are directly hidden by CSS:

```
<style>
    .attributeVal { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: It doesnt work, I'm trying to find out why. I've 1.51, I'll update to 1.72